# How to repeat a drawing horizontally in pygame (drawing done in a class method)?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pygame

This is the task for one of my assignments for my grade 12 coding class, focusing on classes, and inheritance:

> You are going to change things up a little. Your job is to use the basic shapes to create some "faces". Remember that you can create many different basic shapes beyond circles and squares. However, once you create a face, you will create classes of other faces that inherit the shapes but will create new colours. However, unlike the previous assignment, your output should be organized so that the faces are clearly lined up row by row until the screen is filled.

#### Question

What I am trying to do is make a few faces out of shapes, have semi-random colors for each part, and have them repeated horizontally in pygame, and repeating to the next line until the screen is filled. I'm not looking for a full on answer to everything more so ideas on what I can try that might work. I'm stuck on possibly creating a loop that will take the current x & y from my `Face` class and add to it, to have it repeat with a higher x value, repeating the face across the screen.

#### What I've attempted so far

I have the first face drawn, and have it appear exactly where I want. I'm struggling to use my x & y coords from my `__init__` and changing those.

#### Current code

```
import pygame
from random import randint

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

#  defining random colors to work with
randomColor = (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
randomColor1 = (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
randomColor2 = (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
randomColor3 = (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
randomColor4 = (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))
randomColor5 = (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255))

#  creating first face (head, eyes, mouth) at the starting point 0, 0
class Face:
        def __init__(self):
            self.x = 0
            self.y = 0

        def head(self, screen):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (self.x, self.y, 50, 50))

        def eyes(self, screen):
            pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, randomColor1, [self.x + 5, self.y + 15, 10, 10])
            pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, randomColor2, [self.x + 25, self.y + 15, 10, 10])

        def mouth(self, screen):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, randomColor, (self.x + 15, self.y + 35, 30, 7))

#  creating second face with more colors
class Face2(Face):

    def head2(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, randomColor3, [self.x + 5, self.y + 15, 10, 10])

    def eyes2(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randomColor4, (self.x + 5, self.y, 10, 10))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randomColor4, (self.x + 25, self.y, 10, 10))

    def mouth2(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, randomColor5, (self.x, self.y, 30, 7))

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # --- Game logic should go here

    # --- Screen-clearing code goes here

    # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.

    # If you want a background image, replace this clear with blit'ing the
    # background image.
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # --- Drawing code should go here

    my_face = Face()
    my_face.head(screen)
    my_face.eyes(screen)
    my_face.mouth(screen)

    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested `for` loops to create a grid of faces. Modify the `__init__` method so that it takes the `x` and `y` coordinates and assign them to `self.x` and `self.y`. It would also be a good idea to put the `Face` instances into a list instead of recreating them all the time in the main while loop.

```
class Face:
    def __init__(self, x, y):  # Pass the x, y coordinates ...
        self.x = x  # and assign them.
        self.y = y

faces = []  # Put all face instances into this group.
for x in range(0, size[0], 60):  # 0, 60, 120, ..., up to size[0] (exclusive).
    for y in range(0, size[1], 60):
        faces.append(Face(x, y))  # Append the next face instance.


while not done:
    # ...
    # Iterate over the faces to draw them.
    for face in faces:
        face.head(screen)
        face.eyes(screen)
        face.mouth(screen)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would I be putting the nested loops in the main program loop or does it matter specifically, as long as its before it flips the screen?

Comment: Just wanted to update you, thanks again for the response, i got it working perfect!!!! Thanks <3